# how to click on a glyphicon inside a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field with a glyphicon

```
        <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
          <label class="control-label">Nome località: </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="nome_loc" id="nome_loc">
          <i id="cleanLoc" class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
        </div>
```

The output visually is the following (as desired):

[image]

I want to trigger an event on click of the glyphicon but it seems that the event never fires. The js code is the following (in the documentReady block):

```
$('#cleanLoc').click(function(){
  $('#nome_loc').val('');
});
```

This is just to clean the input field. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the `i` element in the DOM inspector you can see that the element has had `pointer-events: none` applied to it by Bootstrap's `forms.less` file. This means that the element does not raise mouse events.

To fix this, override that setting in your own CSS:

```js
$('#cleanLoc').click(function() {
  $('#nome_loc').val('');
});
```

```css
.form-group i { pointer-events: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
  <label class="control-label">Nome località: </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="nome_loc" id="nome_loc">
  <i id="cleanLoc" class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `z-index: 1` style property on `<i id="cleanLoc" class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>`